# Read and Write in XLXS file in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, apache-poi

Below is my ExcelUtils object to read and write data from XLXS file. Excel file placed in src/androidTest/assets folder and I am successfully reading data from excel file in readTestData function and when I am trying to write data in excel using writeTestResult function then code running successfully but data not write in excel file. Plese suggest the issue and resolution

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
import java.io.InputStream
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import java.io.IOException

data class TestData(val className: String, val functionName: String, val inputData: String)

object ExcelUtils {
    private const val FILE_PATH = "test_cases_input.xlsx"
    private const val SHEET_INDEX = 0
    private const val CLASS_NAME_COLUMN = 0
    private const val FUNCTION_NAME_COLUMN = 1
    private const val INPUT_DATA_COLUMN = 2
    private const val EXPECTED_OUTPUT_COLUMN = 3
    private const val TEST_RESULT_COLUMN = 4

    fun readTestData(context: Context, className: String, functionName: String): TestData? {
        val inputStream = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.assets.open(FILE_PATH)
        val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
        val sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(SHEET_INDEX)

        // Find the row based on className and functionName
        val rowIndex = findRowIndex(sheet, className, functionName)
        if (rowIndex == -1) {
            workbook.close()
            inputStream.close()
            return null
        }

        val inputData = sheet.getRow(rowIndex)?.getCell(INPUT_DATA_COLUMN)?.stringCellValue ?: ""

        workbook.close()
        inputStream.close()

        return TestData(className, functionName, inputData)
    }

    fun writeTestResult(context: Context, className: String, functionName: String, result: String) {
        val inputStream = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.assets.open(FILE_PATH)
        val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
        val sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(SHEET_INDEX)

        val rowIndex = findRowIndex(sheet, className, functionName)
        if (rowIndex == -1) {
            workbook.close()
            inputStream.close()
            return
        }

        val row: Row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex) ?: sheet.createRow(rowIndex)
        val cell: Cell = row.getCell(TEST_RESULT_COLUMN) ?: row.createCell(TEST_RESULT_COLUMN)
        cell.setCellValue(result)

        try {
            // Open a file output stream (MODE_PRIVATE for overwriting the file)
            val fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(FILE_PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            // Write the changes to the file
            workbook.write(fileOutputStream)

            // Optionally, you can flush the stream to ensure data is written immediately
            fileOutputStream.flush()
            fileOutputStream.getFD().sync()
            fileOutputStream.close()

            // Log success or other relevant information
            Log.d("WriteTestResult", "Data successfully written to the file.")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Handle IOException (e.g., print the stack trace)
            e.printStackTrace()
            // Log an error message
            Log.e("WriteTestResult", "Error writing data to the file.")
        } finally {
            workbook.close()
            inputStream.close()
        }
    }


    private fun findRowIndex(sheet: Sheet, className: String, functionName: String): Int {
        for (rowIndex in 1..sheet.lastRowNum) {
            val row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex)
            val storedClassName = row?.getCell(CLASS_NAME_COLUMN)?.stringCellValue ?: ""
            val storedFunctionName = row?.getCell(FUNCTION_NAME_COLUMN)?.stringCellValue ?: ""

            if (storedClassName == className && storedFunctionName == functionName) {
                return rowIndex
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception in Logcat? Note that you are not calling `close()` on your `fileOutputStream`. I recommend calling `fileOutputStream.getFD().sync()` and `fileOutputStream.close()` after `fileOutputStream.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for your comment. I have added both the line and then run my code after that code run successfully and I am not getting any error but when I checked in excel file there is no test or any data found. Please check updated code in question

Comment: How are you doing the check? We have no idea. Please add code or tell.

Comment: `context.openFileOutput(FILE_PATH` You call that a path. But it is not a path. Its only a file name. Which is ok. But naming it a path is confusing.

Comment: `Below is my ExcelUtils object to read and write data from XLXS file. Excel file placed in src/androidTest/assets folder` You are only reading a file from assets. Not writing to a file in assets (as that is impossible). Confusing post where you are not telling that you create a file in getFilesDir().

Comment: "when I checked in excel file there is no test or any data found" -- where and how are you looking? The file will not be visible to users, for example.